# mule funciton test cases giving error with maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, mule

When I run my testcase using righclick on project Run as Junit test Its running fine. 
But when I try to run with maven(maven clean install)
I am getting timeout exception.

```
[![INFO  2016-02-01 16:48:28,900 \[Thread-5\] org.mule.module.xml.filters.SchemaValidationFilter: Schema factory implementation: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory@3074311d][1]][1]
```

I am getting continuous above log.
[image: error-log-2]

[image]

Comment: Can you add more info, full stack trace pf timeout and your pom ?

Comment: @MauroRocco I have uploaded error logs

Comment: Hi, you need to show us the exception on the test result that fails, the continuos log is not necessary a synthom of your problem.